# Why str_replace is not replacing correctly

Tags: php, str-replace

Here is my script

```
$searchArray = array("Coupon Codes", "Coupon Code", "Promo", "Promo Codes");

$replaceArray = array("Promo Code", "Promo Codes", "Coupons", "Coupon Code");

$intoString = "Best Buy Coupon Codes";

print str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $intoString);
```

**Result:** Best Buy Coupons Code

**Expected Output:** Best Buy Promo Code

PHP Version 5.6.36

Comment: and actual output? And language version?

Comment: is that an extra 's' i see in the output? Coupon**s** Code?

Comment: I think it is combining 3rd value "Coupons" and half of the 4th value "Code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your unexpected result is that [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will first replace "Coupon Codes" with "Promo Code" and then it will later substitute "Promo" with "Coupons". To work around this, use the array form of [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), which will process the longest strings first, but most importantly will not substitute into any previously substituted text. e.g.

```
$searchArray = array("Coupon Codes", "Coupon Code", "Promo", "Promo Codes");
$replaceArray = array("Promo Code", "Promo Codes", "Coupons", "Coupon Code");
$intoString = "Best Buy Coupon Codes";

// this doesn't work
echo str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $intoString);
// this does
echo strtr($intoString, array_combine($searchArray, $replaceArray));
```

Output:

```
Best Buy Coupons Code
Best Buy Promo Code
```

Answer (score 1):

As on:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.
```

So here's what happens:

Best Buy Coupon Codes -> Best Buy Promo Code (first pair) ->  Best Buy Coupons Code (third pair)

Change `$searchArray` (and `$replaceArray`) it in a way that the next examples doesn't include previous ones in them (i.e. from shortest string to longest string)